# SAPUI5 disable wizard bar

Tags: sapui5, wizard

I control the flow of the wizard through my own methods with nextStep and previousStep. But still I can not control the events of the wizardbar.  I want to disable it. So no event will be fired, when the customer click on any step of the wizard bar.

Any idea how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you **REALLY** want to achieve that, you would have to call some **PRIVATE** API of **Wizard** to disable the tap event from **WizardProgressNavigator**.

In your controller class, put the following code after Wizard is rendered.

```
this.oWizard = this.getView().byId("YOUR_WIZARD_CONTROL_ID");
this.oWizard._getProgressNavigator().ontap = function(){};
```

Comment: Just perfect!! Thank you @Allen

Comment: With this workaround, how can you disable the ability to even click on the different steps of the wizard bar? Your solution works, but the bar is still clickable, any ideas?

Comment: is there a way to undo this? So basically setting the ontap-event back to normal ....