# How can I 'hide' previous views using the sap.m.Wizard component?

Tags: sapui5

In the SAPUI5 library, the sap.m.Wizard [component](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Wizard/preview) navigates from one view to the next in a sequence of steps. I want to utilize this feature, but only display one view at a time.

So if step 2 is displayed, that means step 1 is hidden, if step 3 is displayed, then step 1 and step 2 is hidden.

Can anyone share how this can be achieved?

Comment: I think the [IconTabBar Process flow](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBarProcess/preview) would be more suitable for such a thing

Comment: Yes, but I'm required to use the sap.m.Wizard library for the look and feel

Answer (score 1):

you may need to use the [complete](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Wizard.html#event:complete) event of Wizard.

On completion of each step , you set the visibility of this step to false.

```
onComplete: function(oEvent) {
                var oWizardStep = oEvent.getSource();
                oWizardStep.setVisible(false);
            },
```

Also you also want to [disable user from clicking the Wizard navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388549/sapui5-disable-wizard-bar/42406451#42406451).

Comment: this is half the answer, the second part of this solution would be to include the nextStep() method.

Answer (score 0):

Trapping the 'complete' event did not work for me, however the following did.  Simply add these lines to your .css file in order to see one step at a time in the Wizard with no scroll bar and no previous steps being visible.

```
.sapMWizardStepContainer {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```